# Arduino to RPi serial communication

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send data from an arduino to an RPi and than to a database. But when i run my Python code:

```
import serial
import time
import MySQLdb as mdb

arduino = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0")
arduino.baudrate=9600

data=arduino.readLine()
time.sleep()
data = arduino.readLine()
blah blah blah...
```

IT GIVES ME AN ERROR

> AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'readLine'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Serial doesn't implement `readLine`. Try `read` instead. You probably need to `open` it first also.

https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#classes

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is:

```
arduino.readline()
```

(only lowercase letters in "readline")

Iterations of readings is better to put in loop eg.:

```
while True:
    data=arduino.readLine()
    time.sleep(1)

for x in range(0, 100):
    data=arduino.readLine()
    time.sleep(1)
```